# Show that $A\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{d},\mathbb{R}^{d})$ is hyperbolic.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If a linear flow $(e^{tA})_{t}$ is topologically conjugated to any linear flow $(e^{tB})_{t}$ with $B$ close to $A$, then the vector field $A \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{d},\mathbb{R}^{d})$ is hyperbolic.

---

### Definition

I. $A\colon \mathbb{R}^{d} \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is linear *hyperbolic* if all its eigenvalues ​​have non-zero real part.

II. Let $(f^t)_t$ and $(g^t)_t$ be flows of the following autonomous differential equations $x' = F(x)$, $F: \mathcal{U} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ and $y' = G(y), G: \mathcal{V} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, with $F$ and $G$ continuous funtions defined over open sets. The flows $(f^t)_t$ and $(g^t)_t$ are said to be **topologically conjugate** if there exists a homeomorphism $h: \mathcal{U} \longrightarrow \mathcal{V}$ such that $f^t(x)$ is defined if and only if $g^t(h(x))$ is defined. In such case, $h(f^t(x)) = g^t(h(x))$.

**Attempt:** I started assuming that $A$ was not hyperbolic so I would have one of its eigenvalues ​​to be of the form $i\lambda$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. I tried to build a $B \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{d},\mathbb{R}^{d}) $ operator close to $A$ so that its flows were not topologically conjugated and concluded an absurdity. However, I couldn't finish it.

Every help is welcome.

Comment: This definition of hyperbolic smells strange to me.  It also doesn't match the one I googled here, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicMap.html .  Is this your definition, or are you getting it from a reference (and if so, please share).

Comment: @JakeMirra I'm using a reference in Portuguese (Brazil). http://edo.impa.br/data/_uploaded/Capitulos/Cap6.pdf page 173

Comment: The smallest nontrivial subspaces contained in generalized eigenspaces of imaginary eigenvalues give rise to periodic orbits. But linear hyperbolic flows have no periodic orbits.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks for the idea. I will try to work with her.

Comment: @JohnB  How do I prove this statement? Because I'm trying to see some cases but it doesn't seem so quick and trivial to demonstrate